# Incorporating ASP.NET and Flash Components in One Site

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I need to integrate ASP.NET into an existing Flash site.  The site is heavily laden with Flash and needs to communicate with a SQL Server database.  I want to use ASP.NET SQLDataSource for this purpose.  Given that I need to integrate the two technologies for one web page on the site, do I need to make the site fully ASP.NET with embedded Flash objects?  Or, can I just add a single ASPX page to the site that contains the web.config and connection string to SQL Server?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Does the Flash need to access the SQL server through .NET?  How does it need to interact?  If the Flash component just needs to access data, I'd recommend skipping the .aspx part and just having an HttpHandler that acts as a gateway to the database.  Is Flash JSON-friendly?  If so then it would be fairly easy to just pass relevant arguments to the handler (maybe just URL values) and have it [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) a response.

Comment: We need to query a SQL Server database to get property listings.  Those listings need to be populated in a Flash SWF object.  I've been advised to use ASP.NET as a bridge between Flash and SQL Server.  Is that the best approach?

Comment: @SidC: It's certainly a sensible approach.  Since Flash runs client-side you'll need some kind of server-side gateway between it and the database.  However, since the gateway is just an API and doesn't need a UI, an aspx page is overhead you don't need.  An MVC action would do the job, as would a handler which manually returns data (such as in JSON format).  Possibly even an asmx web service, if Flash can communicate with it via SOAP.  (I don't really know what your options are in Flash, just on the .NET side.)